# Shut off external css for element or line number

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there a command via css/javascript/jquery that shuts off external css(css included through `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>`) for a certain element or starting at a certain line in a file? I am running into a problem with css from a template that my company bought interfering with css, html and jquery elements that I built out separately. The template is pretty robust and I would rather not mess with it. In the end I would like it to be that the template is it's own entity and the code that I add in be none the wiser of the template.

Comment: You'll probably have to explicitly override the styles with a stylesheet of your own.

Comment: Just make a backup copy of the CSS before you mess with it.  Then use Firebug or other developer tools to identify the offending lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there isn't. You need to arrange your existing CSS to do what you want.

By making your CSS "more specific" you can override the other styles.

See: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're saying...you're using this template that works pretty well, but you want to use your own style for the inner content areas without interfering with the main template layout and vice-versa. In that case, I'd make specificity my friend.

There's probably a main content div/section somewhere in there. You can either apply your own class to that div:

`<div id="some_id_from_your_template" class="my_class">`

...or nest another div inside:

`<div id="some_id_from_your_template">
  <div class="my_class">`

This will give you a somewhat clean slate so you can apply your own styles to `.my_class` and everything inside it.

```
.my_class { //new style rules that will only apply to my stuff}
.my_class p { //only applies to paragraphs within my_class }
.my_class a { //only applies to anchors within my_class }
//etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can continue to include the robust template and then link to your own specific CSS file (i.e. include two CSS files). In your personal CSS file just [reset the CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset) for what you don't want to use the template for.

Or simply redefine a style. If the robust template uses

```
table.class
```

Then redefine table.class in your own CSS file which you include AFTER the robust template.